# Intellisense issue with imported models in pycharm

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, pycharm

Using pycharm with python3 I have an issue when trying to access methods from one class in a file structure to imported into another. I can use the methods but they aren't pre-filled by intellisense which makes it very difficult since I am just learning python. my files are as follows:

```
tictactoe
---- gameplay
|       |--->migrations
|       |---> init.py
|       |---> admin.py
|       |---> models.py
|       |---> test.py
|       |---> views.py
---- player
        |---> migrations
        |--->templates
        |---> __init__.py
        |---> admin.py
        |---> apps.py
        |---> models.py
        |---> tests.py
        |---> utils.py
        |---> views.py
```

Gameplay/Models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals # if you use this put this first
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

GAME_STATUS_CHOICES = (
   ('F', 'First Player To Move'),
   ('S', 'Second Player To Move'),
   ('W', 'First Player Wins'),
   ('L', 'Second Player Wins'),
   ('D', 'Draw')
)

class GameQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def games_for_user(self, user):

        return self.filter(
            Q(first_player=user) | Q(secondplayer=user)
        )

    def active(self):
        return self.filter(
            Q(status='F') | Q(status='S')
        )


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Game(models.Model):
    first_player = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="games_first_player", 
on_delete=models.CASCADE)
second_player = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="games_second_player", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
last_active = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
status = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='F', choices=GAME_STATUS_CHOICES)

# returns a manager object, lets us interact with result set
objects = GameQuerySet.as_manager()

def __str__(self):
    return "{0} vs {1}".format(self.first_player,  self.second_player)
```

player/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from gameplay.models import Game


def home(request):
    my_games = Game.objects.games_for_user(request.user)
    active_games = my_games.active()

    return render(request, "player/home.html",
                   {'games':active_games}
```

so my code runs and functions correctly but when I type Game.objects. (games_for_user) doesn't show up, even when i press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>. I have found that if I do <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> it will pop up sometimes but not by normal intellisense. The same thing goes for when I type my_games. (active doesn't show up). Also as a learning experience is there a better way to show file structure than what I have.

EDIT:

I have found that if I preface my variable my_games with a return type like this

```
 my_games: GameQuerySet = Game.objects.games_for_user(request.user)
 active_games = my_games.active()  (<- active did show up)
```

I was just wondering if my objects = GameQuerySet.as_manager() is preventing my intellisense from predicting because it doesn't know what the return type is? If anyone could clarify this for me or solve my original problem that would be great help in my learning.

Comment: You can do this by giving PyCharm what is source root, then it will search for your modules on source roots. More you can read this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/content-root.html it will give good understanding on what is needed to do n PyCharm to import you'r own modules. :)

Comment: Thank you! I think I am on  the right track, so my top level folder tictactoe was already a content folder. I also learned how you can't have content folders on a deeper level than that one already instantiated. I tried marking both tictactoe/player and tictactoe/gameplay as source folders to no avail either. Is there some kind of refresh I have to do to the project?

Comment: I don't think Source Root has something to do here. The problem is not related to `PYTHONPATH`, PyCharm is confused by `games_for_user` return type. Most likely it's [PY-22616](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-22616) issue. Btw completion for `games_for_user` works fine for me, feel free to create another ticket in PyCharm bug tracker and attach the whole project (if possible) there.

Comment: Yes as I mentioned in my edit and your comment that was the issue. I noticed Intellisense worked for other functions and classes. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something else I found was that I had the community edition of pycharm which doesn't natively support intellisense for web development. I upgraded and a lot of what I was expecting to pop up finally did. I didn't have a concrete solution to my question so I put this here for future searches for beginners. Good luck everyone.